# Vue js - Declare and use variables in DOM

Tags: vuejs2

Is it possible to declare and use simple variables only in the DOM in vue? Instead of having irrelevant variables in the script section.

Sort of like this:

```
 <button v-on:click="show = true">Hey there!</button>
  <div v-if="show">
  show me
  </div>
```

This works in angular:

http://jsfiddle.net/0kq1nazr/1/

But as far as I can see it doesn´t work in vue js.